# BSON error creating new BsonDocument for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, nosql

I'm new to MongoDB and, after some tutorials, I'm trying to read data from my SQL Server database and reverse them in MongoDB, with C# and Entity Framework.

I found this code on MongoDB site:

```
async static void addDoc()
{
    var document = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "address" , new BsonDocument
            {
                { "street", "2 Avenue" },
                { "zipcode", "10075" },
                { "building", "1480" },
                { "coord", new BsonArray { 73.9557413, 40.7720266 } }
            }
        },
        { "borough", "Manhattan" },
        { "cuisine", "Italian" },
        { "grades", new BsonArray
            {
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "date", new DateTime(2014, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                    { "grade", "A" },
                    { "score", 11 }
                },
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "date", new DateTime(2014, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                    { "grade", "B" },
                    { "score", 17 }
                }
            }
        },
        { "name", "Vella" },
        { "restaurant_id", "41704620" }
    };

    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
}
```

It works as I expect. So, I made this:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    foreach (var trans in db.TRANSACTIONS)
    {
        try
        {
            var document = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "ID", erog.ID.ToBson() },
                { "CUSTOMER" , new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "CSTID", trans.CUSTOMERS.CSTID.ToBson() },
                        { "NAME", trans.CUSTOMERS.NAME.ToBson()},
                        { "CITY", trans.CUSTOMERS.CITY.ToBson() },
                        { "ZIP", trans.CUSTOMERS.ZIP.ToBson() },
                        { "STATE", trans.CUSTOMERS.STATE.ToBson() },
                    }
                },
                { "TRANSACTIONNUMBER", trans.TRANSACTIONNUMBER.ToBson() },
                { "TIMESTAMP", erog.TIMESTAMP.ToBson() },
                { "AMOUNT", erog.AMOUNT.ToBson() },
                { "PAYMENT", erog.PAYMENT.ToBson() },
            };

            var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("transactions");
            collection.InsertOne(document);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to execute this code, I get an error when executing *var document = new BsonDocument {....}*; the error is "**A string value cannot be written to the root level of a bson document**". So, as you can see, I tried to put the *.ToBson()* at the end of my values, but the result is still the same.

The only difference is the value isn't a string between two quotation marks, but it is a real value from my table.

How can I reach my goal and create&insert a document in my MongoDB database, starting from my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, dumb question, dumb solution.

Just replace all *toBson()* with *toString()* and now it works! :)